# How does the object/boolean equivalence work in python?

Tags: python

Coming from javascript, I found pretty bizarre this behaviour:

```py
>>> empty_list = []
>>> empty_list == True
False
>>> empty_list is True
False
>>> empty_list is False
False
>>> empty_list == False
False
```

And on the other hand:

```
>>> one_list = [1]
>>> one_list is False
False
>>> one_list is True
False
>>> one_list == False
False
>>> one_list == True
False
```

Actually, I expected that since:

```
if []:
  pass # This never done
```

and

```
if [4]:
  pass # This is always done
```

and

```
>>> not []
True
>>> not [1]
False
```

A list would convert to a boolean.

I am aware that

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1])
True
```

So I wonder why `not` and `if` perform this conversion, whereas nor `in` nor `==` do

Is there any formal explanation for this?

Comment: Strange, `bool(empty_list)` returns False on my machine. What version are you using?

Comment: `is` tests whether its operands are the same exact object; this is stronger than equality.  Only `True` is `True`.

Comment: I'm voting "could not reproduce" because `bool([])` is `False` on both Python 2 and Python 3, and I have no idea why you expect the `is` tests to work at all. Obviously no kind of list "is" the boolean singleton of either value.

Comment: Because if not something is True, I expect something to be False

Comment: You are coming from javascript and find Python boolean equivalence incosistent?

Comment: Well `bool([]) == False` and `not bool([]) == True` as you expect, so it seems this is a duplicate, because all that's left of this question stems from your misunderstanding and misapplication of `is` tests.

Comment: You seem to have now changed your question to invalidate existing answers. Your new question at the bottom is partially internally inconsistent "why ... `if` performs this conversion, whereas... `if` [does not]" and partly self-explanatory. `not` performs a conversion to boolean because its entire purpose is to take the boolean negation. `==` does not convert types in Python probably because such behavior has led to a hideous mess in languages like JavaScript and PHP that did go down this road, and which now have dire warnings about using `==` because it's not even transitive.

Comment: I indeed did change the question, but it was not in order to invalidate existent answers, but to clarify what my problem was. My first version was confusing, and led to the answers I got.

I'm actually used to javascript way, and the one I find confusing is python's, actually the answers still apply to the new version of the question. I'm sorry for the mess

Answer (score 8):

`is` is an operator that checks object equality.  In other words, `a is b` is true if and only if `a` and `b` are two names pointing to the same object in memory.

If you just want plain regular equality or inequality, use `==` or `!=`.  But note a Boolean will never be equal to a list, because they're simply not the same type.  No implicit conversion occurs in Python as it does in Javascript.  You still need to explicitly convert the list in Boolean before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation might be [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence): `is` binds more strongly than `not`, so

```
not [1] is True
```

is evaluated as

```
not ([1] is True])
== not (False)      # because a list containing 1 is not the boolean True
== True
```